# Do I need to turn over the soil when vermicomposting?

Tags: vermicomposting

In most of the websites they say that I need to maintain a good airflow in my worm bin to prevent making it anaerobic, but most websites only says that I need to have a good worm beddings and enough holes. For me it seems reasonable to turn over the soil, putting the soil from bottom part to the top part, do you think it is good?

I've asked this question because my worm bin seems okay but after digging I notice that there are many spoil foods at the middle part, the smell is very bad.

Answer (score 6):

It is likely you are feeding them incorrectly based on your previous question.  African night crawlers are surface feeders but you've been placing food below the surface.  They feed on the surface and drag decaying food into their burrows.  For this reason you should not disturb the bin as you'll destroy their burrows.  And you should only feed as much as they remove by the morning.

If the bin is an anaerobic pile now, you will likely have to move them to a new bin.  However, if you can remove the decomposing food, you can start to surface feed them only as much as they can eat